# Laravel 6.x Backpack NewsCrud Plugin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

What I want to do is allow the admin panel to post news using newscrud. I am confused in how would I grab the information from the database and show the user the articles.

I am having trouble using the newscrud plugin for laravel. I quite don't understand how to use this plugin. I have installed it using composer. All the controllers, models etc. are in the vendor folder in my Laravel project.

***Attempts:***
What I tried to do is make a function in the 
laravel-project/vendor/backpack/newscrud/src/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ArticleCrudController.php file:

```
public function index()
{
    # Pass the article database information in articles var
    $articles = Articles::all();

    # Return this variable to blog page
    return view ('blog')->with('articles', $articles);
}
```

And in the routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('/blog', 'ArticleCrudController@index')->name('blog');
```

**Front-end code**

```
                      @foreach($articles as $article)

                          <div class="col-md-12 d-flex ftco-animate">

                            <div class="blog-entry align-self-stretch d-md-flex">

                              <a href="blog-single.html" class="block-20" style="background-image: url('images/image_6.jpg');">

                              </a>

                              <div class="text d-block pl-md-4">

                                <div class="meta mb-3">

                                  <div><a href="#">July 20, 2019</a></div>

                                  <div><a href="#">Admin</a></div>

                                  <div><a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 3</a></div>

                                </div>

                                <h3 class="heading"><a href="#">Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts</a></h3>

                                <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>

                                <p><a href="blog-single.html" class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3">Read more</a></p>

                              </div>

                            </div>

                          </div>

                    @endforeach
```

**Error**
The error message I get is:

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleCrudController] does not exist.
```

If you need information/screenshots I am willing to provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using composer in PHP, you should never make modifications to files inside the /vendor/ folder. Because as soon as you run composer update, they will get overwritten.

If I understand correctly, What you’re trying to do has little to do with Backpack. You should not overwrite the package in the vendor folder. You should create a controller in your app folder, with a routes in your routes folder, line you would normally do in Laravel. Just make sure that, when you reference the model, you reference Backpack\NewsCRUD\app\Models\Article instead of App\Models\Article.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow! It does works but I haven't did composer update! This is a good solution! Thanks!

Comment: Added the fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
App\Http\Controllers\ArticleCrudController
```

show that Laravel is not able to resolve the controller in the PHP namespace `App\Http\Controllers`.

I just looked into the library's code and I suggest you to replace

```php
Route::get('/blog', 'ArticleCrudController@index')->name('blog');
```

by

```php
Route::get('/blog', 'Backpack\\NewsCRUD\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\ArticleCrudController@index')->name('blog');
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly I get a new error message: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Backpack\NewsCRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleCrudController] does not exist. It seems to still want to grab from the app folder in the main project directory instead of vender.

Comment: Try to move the route declaration at the end of the bootstrap/app.php, just beturn the return $app;

Comment: Do I return the vender directory? How would I move the route declaration?

Comment: Do I add the route declaration Route::get('/blog', 'Backpack\\NewsCRUD\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\ArticleCrudController@index')->name('blog');
before the return?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your web.php like this:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '/',
    'middleware' => ['web'],
    // This is all the namespace in directory
    'namespace' => 'laravel-project\vendor\backpack\newscrud\src\app\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () {
    Route::get('/blog', 'ArticleCrudController@index')->name('blog');
});
```

And edit your ArticleCrudController.php file to:

```
namespace laravel-project\vendor\backpack\newscrud\src\app\Http\Controllers\Admin;
```

Hope this can help :)